# C++ map brace initialization and unique ptr

Tags: c++, dictionary, c++14, std, unique-ptr

Why can't I use map's braces initialization with unique_ptr?

Edit: I use gcc 7.2 in c++17 mode.

I can create and insert into unordered map using make_pair and the [] operator.

```
std::unordered_map<std::string, std::unique_ptr<A>> map;

map.insert(std::make_pair("hello",std::make_unique<A>()));
map["foo"] = std::make_unique<A>();
```

But I can't figure out why it fails when using braces.

```
map.insert({"foo", std::make_unique<A>()}); // Error
```

> error: use of deleted function ‘std::pair<_T1, _T2>::pair(const std::pair<_T1, _T2>&)

Comment: You are using C++14, because before there was no `std::make_unique`.

Comment: afaik insert copies (unique_ptr is uncopyable), use emplace

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since C++11, associative container insertion requires either *copy-costructible* lvalues or *move-insertable* mutable rvalues. So, there's no problem invoking `insert()` along with `make_pair()` as you do: the latter constructs a `pair<const char[],unique_ptr>` that is used to initialize a `value_type` rvalue.

The problem with the brace initialization is that (until C++17) the value_type const& overload gets preferred (because there's no proper value_type&& overload), hence a copy is requested and an error is raised.

Indeed, note that both forms compile in gcc trunk and clang 5(with libc++) in c++17 mode.

---

More precisely, from C++11 on, the relevant insert semantic requirements read

> **[unord.req]** If t is a non-const rvalue expression, value_type shall be MoveInsertable into X; otherwise, value_type shall be CopyInsertable into X.

is the actual members specification where things differ; until C++17, we have:

```
pair<iterator, bool> insert(const value_type& obj);
template <class P> pair<iterator, bool> insert(P&& obj);
...
```

where the generic overload is SFINAE constrained to `std::is_constructible<value_type, P&&>::value`. Clearly, using a *braced-init-list* will select the const& overload here (note: there's also an initializer_list overload, but it does not apply to the OP case).

Instead, in C++17 we also have

```
pair<iterator, bool> insert(value_type&& obj);
```

Comment: looks like gcc support for c++17 is still experimental (https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx-status.html), that's why it doesn't compile for me (gcc 7.2). Great explanation. Thanks.